# gc() and rm(list=ls()) and restarting doesn't clear memory

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection, rstudio

I was doing data wrangling with Rstudio, and while I was doing something with a very large dataset, the process died. I restarted the computer, but ever since Rstudio has not been responsive or slow due to memory limits (currently, it's occupying 8gb of my 16gb RAM).

I tried doing all the standard things I found on Stackoverflow.

1. `gc()` and `gc(reset=T)`
2. `rm(list = ls())`
3. `.rs.restartR()`
4. Restart my computer.

But when I open Rstudio, the memory usage would quickly climb and make the entire thing unresponsive. Has anyone faced anything similar?

I am using Windows 10, R 3.4.1, Rstudio 1.0.153.
`gc(result = T)` output results in

```
Ncells 1311025 70.1    2164898 115.7  1311025 70.1
Vcells 2368039 18.1    3851194  29.4  2368039 18.1
```

I've never had such a problem and now I'm baffled as to why memory is not being released. Does anybody have some advice?

- Added 11:03am: I deleted .RHistory (plus, there was no .Rdata), and unchecked all autoloading global options. The problem is still persisting, with occasional error messages of "Error: Unable to establish connection with R session" when I try reloading.

Comment: Assure to delete the `.Rhistory` and `.Rdata` files in the working directory. When you open R or Rstudio, it searches for the above files to restore a session. Likely there are huge objects to load.

Comment: Here is one thing to check: See if your rstudio session is automatically loading a bunch of stuff. `Tools > Global Options`, then un-click `Restore most recently...`, `Restore .RData into...`  I also have `Save workspace ...` set to `Never`.

Comment: @nicola Ah yes, I already performed that part---should have written it in my original post.

Comment: @lmo Neither worked. :-( Can you suggest some other solutions I might try out?

Comment: Here's a simple thing to check. Start your program manager (or similar in another OS, eg `top` in Linux) to check your memory usage. Open R studio. Does your memory usage explode? if yes, then there is likely some additional box to uncheck (I am currently working with an old version of rstudio). If no, then something in your script is causing this growth and you should take a closer look, perhaps running it line by line to see what is going on.

Comment: @lmo I think I pinpointed roughly to what's wrong. Rstudio itself isn't having a problem. Opening the R notebook that I was working on triggers the memory increment---I still haven't figured out why, because as soon as I open the document in Rstudio, memory usage explodes and things grind to a halt. Let me try just working on terminal or copy-pasting the existing markdown to see if that does the trick... I still don't understand though.

Comment: I'm having the same/a similar problem.  gc() shows Ncells and Vcells at near 90% of my memory (24GB) and I've deleted all .RData files as well as cleared my workspace and ls() shows nothing.  Can't figureit out