# R how to clear memory

Tags: r

Here's my problem:
I'm working on a Linux system and run R in a console.
Within an R programs loop, I load a really huge Data file, several GB.
Pseudocode:

```
for(i in 1:n){ 
  data=read(Hugefile[i])
  ...
  # do some stuff
  ...
  rm(data)
}
```

When R was started new from console, the first iteration loads the data successfully. But in the second iteration, I get an allocation error. Even when I clear everything by using `rm(list=ls())` and `gc()`, I get the same error trying to load this file manually. First, when I close R and open it again, I then can load another file of that size.

Does anyone know how to clear the memory of R within a loop and without restarting R?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: this question is a duplicate but not an answered one. still maybe it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530832/gc-and-rmlist-ls-and-restarting-doesnt-clear-memory

Comment: What does ```gc()``` say before and after the first iteration (and the ```rm(data)``` call)?